# module object has no attribute type getaddrinfo

Tags: python, sockets, import

I have this really weird python problem and I really need to help to figure this out
When I run

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import socket

socket.getaddrinfo("www.google.com", 80)
```

I get this error

```
socket.getaddrinfo("www.google.com", 80)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'getaddrinfo'
```

Can anyone help me with this

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't you have file named 'socket.py' in your work space?

If so, you should rename it, or put it into some subdirectory.

Comment: ooooh, very nice catch